# java без использований условных операторов

Tags: java

Здравствуйте, помогите решить задачу без использования условных операторов, не совсем понимаю как это можно реализовать.
Задача:  Даны два целых числа: A, B. Проверить истинность высказывания: «Каждое из чисел A и B нечетное».
Примеры:

```
Введите число A: 3
Введите число B: 9

Ответ: true

Введите число A: 4
Введите число B: 9

Ответ: false
```

Comment: A%2 != 0 && B%2 != 0

Comment: Вам нужна программа на java? Тернарный оператор в условиях вашей задачи как рассматривается? Как условный? Или важно только отсутствие ключевых слов if-then-else?

Comment: да на java. Тернарный оператор, рассматривается как условный.

Comment: а while можно использовать?

Comment: подсказка: `System.out.println( (new boolean[] {false, true})[f(a, b)] );`. метод `int f(int a, int b)` возвращает 1, если оба числа нечетные (при взятии остатка от деления на 2 дают 1), иначе 0.

Comment: А что относится к условным операторам?

Answer (score 3):

```
Integer c = (a+1)%2+(b+1)%2;
Boolean r = c.equals(0);
System.out.println(r);
```

Answer (score 1):

А вы словите исключение :)

```
try{
    int a = 2;
    a = a % 2;
    int temp = a/a;
    System.out.println("True");
} catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println("False");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Да все просто же

```
private void print(int a, int b) {
    for(int i = 2; i<= a % 2 + b % 2; i++) {
        System.out.println("true");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println("false");
}


    print(2, 10); // false
    print(2, 9); // false
    print(4, 9); // false
    print(3, 9); // true
```

или так (если вообще запрещены все знаки сравнения)

```
private void print(int a, int b) {
    try {
        int[] arr = new int[a % 2 + b % 2 - 2];
        System.out.println("true");
    } catch (RuntimeException exp) {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
}
```